# PHP random number 1-20 output

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm trying to output 20 images, which are all numbered in the named files 1-20.png. Instead of outputting them in order I want to randomise the output.

Originally I had this but it is obviously very static and there must be a way to maybe use the foreach loop but just output numbers rather than an array.

Also, it shouldn't repeat numbers.

```
<?php
foreach (array_rand($numbers, 19) as $key)
    echo '<div class="avatar"><img src="' . $numbers[$key] . '.png" /></div>';
?>
```

Then had numbers 1-20 stored as string in an array on the page.

Comment: `$order = array_shuffle(range(1,20)); foreach($order as $id) { echo $id; }`

Comment: @h2ooooooo bah! I alternate between PHP and bash all day, things keep bleeding over...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe take a look at [`shuffle`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)?

Something like this:

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 20);
shuffle($numbers);

foreach ($numbers as $number) {

    echo $number;
}
```

Comment: Do you think an array is the way to go then? Rather than using integers.

Comment: @Francesca Yep, you have to use an array (`array_shuffle`/`rand()+isset()`) either way or you'll most likely (it's random after all) have duplicates. Just loop through the array after a shuffle with a simple `for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)`.

Comment: @Francesca if duplicates should be avoided, a set/list needs to be maintained. (OP not clear towards this)